# OMG withdraw to Ledger Nano S

Tags: wallets, wallet-transfer

I attempted to withdraw and transfer my balance of OMG currency to my local Ledger S drive. It shows complete but I do not see anything on my Ledger and the address is correct. Is there any way to recover this? I really do not know why it did not transfer.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x666f669a4c5d673350acad0278d7200dbd04dbd1bc27d337df34788bf1d45362

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It did transfer and you can check your balance on Etherscan as well.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x6daca8a2016a971d877fb6280f1a6ae24199590e

The Ledger doesn't show it on the Ethereum wallet, but you can use MyEtherWallet to transfer them out of your ledger.

- Plug in your ledger to your computer.
- Navigate to the ETH wallet and open it.
- In the 'options' turn web support 'ON'
- In google chrome, go to MyEtherWallet
- Go to 'view wallet info' in the top menu
- Select ledger wallet and connect

Answer (score 0):

It **did** transfer.

`0x6daca8a2016a971d877fb6280f1a6ae24199590e` now has 27.99 OMG tokens.

A Ledger nano S just stores a private key. If the private key for that address 'on' your Ledger, then the tokens are (to all extents and purposes).

Perhaps you just can not see them on the interface? I don't know if Ledger supports displaying all these tokens in their interface.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. The Ledger is definitely not showing any OMG tokens on the interface. I have emailed Ledger support about this and awaiting their response. I wonder if I can send them even if they are not showing on the software?